# When to pump up and down?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma, pushdown-automata

When I'm solving a question I usually spent too much time testing whether I should pump or down? Is there any formula to know when to use which?

Also, on proofing non context free grammar we use three pumping lemma, and one that's confused me is $|uvy| \le p$. I mean in the example given in the book I read, it is not even used. Can someone please tell on which situation this is will be useful?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "pump up" and "pump down"?  (Also, in the first sentence you mention "pump or down"; is that a typo?)  2. Please, one question per question.  You ask two different questions; they should be posted separately as 2 separate questions.  This format is not well-suited to asking multiple different questions in one post.  Please edit to remove one of the questions from this post and ask it in a separate post.

Comment: Though it has limits, and also more powerful versions (such as Ogden's
lemma), the pumping lemma (for regular or CF languages) is quite
powerful in the way it allows you to set restrictive conditions to be
used for establishing a contradiction. While $|uvy|\leq p$ is often
needed, there are cases when it is not (for example, existence of any
pumpable part is enough for languages that have unbouded gaps in the
possible size of words). But it is often the case in math that you
need not use in full all the possible consequences of the given
hypotheses.

Answer (score 3):

To fix symbols, let us choose the decomposition $z = uvwxy$.

One of the examples where $|vwx|\le p$ comes in, is the language $L =\{ a^mb^na^mb^n\mid m,n\ge 1\}$.

Start with the "generic" string $a^pb^pa^pb^p$ where $p$ is the pumping constant. To have any chance of finding a pumping pair $v,x$ such that $uv^iwx^iy$ is within the language is by choosing $v$ in the first set of $a$'s and $x$ in the second set of $a$'s (or similarly for the $b$'s). Now the length of $vwx$ will be more than $p$ as it contains all $b$'s between the two sets of $a$'s.

Without that restriction $L$ can be pumped, and the pumping lemma is no longer suited for proving $L$ is not context-free.